# How to get fully qualified name of an IFile?

Tags: java

I use the following code for trying to get the fully qualified name of an IFile object.

```
private String getFullName(IFile file) {
   IJavaElement element = JavaCore.create(file);
      if (element instanceof IType) {
         return ((IType) element).getFullyQualifiedName().toString();
      } else {
         return new String(((CompilationUnit) element).getFileName());
      }
}
```

In case that the IFile object is a class, the method returns e.g. the following String:

```
/TestProject/src/testPackage.TestClass.java
```

What I want is the fully qualified name without the Project Name and the src folder. But how can I achieve that?

The path I'm looking for would look like this (package declaration + class name):

```
testPackage.TestClass.java
```

Comment: So you want a relative path?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java File to unpack a full path into the filename and remove the directories

```
// assuming the above routine - getFullName
File fullNameAsFile = new File(getFullName(iFile));

String namePart = fullNameAsFile.getName();
```